# GET from CloudFront after PUT returns old data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using CloudFront to access my S3 bucket. 
I perform both GET and PUT operations to retrieve and update the data. The problem is that after i send PUT request with new data, GET request still returns the older data. I do see that the file is updated in S3 bucket.
I am performing both GET and PUT from iOS application. However, i tried performing GET request using regular browsers and i still receive older data. 
Do i need to do anything in addition to make CloudFront refresh its data?

Comment: Are you sure that the put request is successful? There is usually a clear cache call you can make with these services and you can often do it manually. If you do that you might see that the PUT request was successful or not.

Comment: Yes, i see that the data was changed in the S3 bucket

Answer (score 2):

Cloudfront caches your data. How long depends on the headers the origin serves content with and the distribution settings.

Amazon has a [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) with the full results of how they interac, but if you haven't set your cache control headers, not changed any cloudfront settings, then by default data is cached for upto 24 hours.

You can either:

- set headers indicating how long to cache content for (e.g. `Cache-Control: max-age=300` to allow caching for up to 5 minutes). How exactly you do this depends on how you are uploading the content, at a pinch you can use the console
- Use the console / api to invalidate content. Beware that only the first 1000 invalidations a month a free - beyond that amazon charges. In addition, invalidations take 10-15 minutes to process.
- Change the naming strategy for your s3 data so that new data is served under a different name (perhaps less relevant in your case)

Answer (score 1):

When you `PUT` an object into S3 by sending it through Cloudfront, Cloudfront *proxies* the `PUT` request back to S3, without *interpreting* it within Cloudfront... so the `PUT` request changes the S3 object, but the old version of the object, if cached, would have no reason to be evicted from the Cloudfront cache, and would continue to be served until it is expired, evicted, or invalidated.

"The" Cloudfront cache is not a single thing.  Cloudfront has over 50 global edge locations (reqests are routed to what should be the closest one, using geolocating DNS), and objects are only cached in locations through which they have been requested.  Sending an invalidation request to purge an object from cache causes a background process at AWS to contact all of the edge locations and request the object be purged, if it exists.

What's the point of uploading this way, then?  The point has to do with the impact of packet loss, latency, and overall network performance on the throughput of a TCP connection.

The Cloudfront edge locations are connected to the S3 regions by high bandwidth, low loss, low latency (within the bounds of the laws of physics) connections... so the connection from the "back side" of Cloudfront towards S3 may be a connection of higher quality than the browser would be able to establish.

Since the Cloudfront edge location is also likely to be closer to the browser than S3 is, the browser connection is likely to be of higher quality and more resilient... thereby improving the net quality of the end-to-end logical connection, by splitting it into two connections.  This feature is solely about performance:

http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/

If you don't have any issues sending directly to S3, then uploads "through" Cloudfront serve little purpose.